# Has "f**k" lost its profanity?

Tags: offensive-language

I thought that "fuck" was quite vulgar and offensive. However it's used by a nine year old main character in a book aimed at children and young teenagers.

> [...] even though he told him to fuck off [...]
>
> *'Fuck off, Mr. Fox.'*
>
> It never seemed to stop him [...]

So, has "fuck" become a mild swear word appropriate in children's literature?

Comment: I think this is essentially a matter of opinion, some people have always been more offended by swearing than others.However, swearing in (social) media is quite common, so frequent exposure to it may lessen the impact.

Comment: What's the title of the book, because I doubt that book was meant for 7 year olds.

Comment: It's "The Green Tracksuit (1)" by Peter Gordon Elliot. The book is described as appropriate for "Age Level: 7 - 18".

Comment: @KillingTime I do agree with you is a matter of opinion. My opinion is ***common doesn't mean it is an appropriate thing to do***.

Comment: The book cover design is not 7 year old friendly either ***in my humble opinion***.

Comment: There are two issues mixed up in your question. I want to say “No! Words like f’ck are not appropriate in young children’s literature.” but I also believe that these words are no longer nearly as vulgar and offensive as they used to be and their use is possible in respectful adult settings. Slurs are now much more likely to be the source of the real “gut punches” of personal abuse (see: https://theconversation.com/wtf-slurs-offend-young-adults-more-than-swearing-125193).

Comment: Are you sure the book is really aimed at 7 year olds, and if so by whom? It seems to be self-published, so presumably the author can put any age limit on it without seriously considering its appropriateness, or it may have an automated reading age figure based on analysis of sentence length and similar statistics.

Comment: I would definitely say it's a book for adults, according to the preview and the reviews: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Green-Tracksuit-Peter-Gordon-Elliot/dp/024494184X I've only answered now because I checked back. If you want to notify a user, please use @ followed by their username e.g. @strah

Comment: "But a sinister encounter late one night on a country road, turns his world upside down, exposing him to grave danger, which will haunt him forever. . ." Probably not used in second grade classrooms...